# useVisibleTask does not work in Qwik because it is not a function

Tags: qwik

I'm trying to use `Swiper` in my Qwik application. Based on the [docs](https://qwik.builder.io/docs/components/lifecycle/#usevisibletask) I figured out that I have to use `useVisibleTask$`.

This is my code:

```
import {
    component$,
    useVisibleTask$,
} from '@builder.io/qwik'
import Swiper from 'swiper'
import 'swiper/css'

const Courses = component$(() => {

    useVisibleTask$(() => {

        const swiper = new Swiper(`.swiper`, {
            loop: true,
            pagination: {
                el: '.swiper-pagination',
            },

            navigation: {
                nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
            },

            scrollbar: {
                el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
            },
        })
    })

    retrun <div>Courses HTML here</div>
})

export default Courses
```

And this is the error that I get:

> **vite_ssr_import_1**.useVisibleTaskQrl is not a function

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

`useVisibleTask$()` registers a hook to be executed when the component becomes visible in the viewport, it will run at least once in the browser, and it can be reactive and re-executed when some tracked signal or store changes.

So from the error, it seems your project is SSR which is on the server. If that's the case, it means the `useVisibleTask$` hook won't be available.